# Algorithm to find minimal subsets that intersect with list of sets

Tags: algorithm, set, combinatorics, set-intersection

Problem statement:

> Given a list L of sets, find every set X of elements such that:
>
> 1. for all Y in L, the intersection of X and Y is non-empty
> 2. the set X is minimal in the sense that no element in X can be removed and still satisfy property #1

I have a feeling this is a known / already studied problem, and I'd like to read up on the algorithms for it. However after reading about various set problems and algorithms, I have yet to find one that matches this. (Or maybe I didn't realize it could be rephrased to match my problem, as such problem transformations are often not obvious to me.)

The closest I've found so far is discussions of something called the "Set Intersection Problem" ( example: https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0053 ), but that is just looking for elements that are in all the sets. So it is related, but much more restrictive than what I am considering.

I eventually was able to write some algorithms with some heuristic approaches that work okay for my purposes currently, so I really am more interested in finding what this problem is called, or literature references, but interesting code snippets would of course be educational as well.

Comment: For set theory, you might have better luck over in [mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com). Stackoverflow is for specific question about specific code.

Comment: If you're looking for a set X of **minimum size**, then the problem can be quite hard, but if you're just looking for a **minimal** set X then it's extremely easy. Just start with `X = union of all the sets` and then remove elements from X until you can't remove any element.

Comment: You want to enumerate all [minimal hitting sets](https://cs.nyu.edu/~shasha/papers/glife/algorithm.html#:~:text=hitting%20set%20problem%3A-,Definition%3A,will%20destroy%20the%20hitting%20set.). If you go looking for algorithms, there's an equivalent formulation that involves enumerating minimal set covers.

Comment: If you want to enumerate all minimal sets X then you can do it this way: start with X = union of all sets; find the next element of X than can be removed; then make two recursive calls, one where this element is removed, and one where this element is marked as "don't remove".

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I wish I could mark your comment as the answer. Sometimes the appropriate key words are all it takes to open up a world of solutions. Thanks.

Comment: @PPenguin feel free to self-answer (and credit me, if you like).